# Salesforce Bulk API job priority

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, salesforce

I have a tree of hierarchical data. After tree is built (~300k nodes of 16 different types) I need to push it into Salesforce 16 custom objects in a specific order, parents first then childs, so I have 16 jobs with batches inside.

The problem is that Salesforce handles jobs in parallel and random order so mapping by external ID is failed all the time, childs may be inserted earlier so on.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Apex Flex Queue](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue) to actively manage the order of the queued jobs to control which batch jobs are processed first.

```
public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Your processing logic here
        // Chain this job to next job by submitting the next job
        System.enqueueJob(new SecondJob());
    }
}
```